# 3-dots at the end of a clip text cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there any helper functions in Google Apps Script to add "..." in cell where the text is in "clip" mode ?

I mean from this:

```
| My sample te|
```

to this:

```
| My sample...|
```

I saw that Google implemented lately in GAS the CLIP wrap strategy ([API reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setwrapstrategystrategy)) but I see nothing regarding the formatting.

If I have to do it manually, how can I correlate the cell size with the text size?

Comment: Can it be done manually through the UI?

Comment: I already generate this text through the apps script. Either it could be an auto formatting from the UI (kind of conditional formatting) or a script to split my text and add the dots according to the cell fixed size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

***There's no wrap strategy to do so, as you mentioned the only way to reach your goal is by using a custom trigger function like*** `onEdit(e)` ***and then change the current value of the cell but keep in mind there should be a place to store your current value.***

As a workaround/idea I would use the cell note functionality to store the value and set the value with 3-dots afterwards. But this is not ideally the best solution.

### Code

In order to handle the event object, open the bound script and use:

```
function onEdit(e){
  let range = e.range;
  let currentColumn = range.getColumn();
  let currentSheet = range.getSheet();
  let columnWidth = currentSheet.getColumnWidth(currentColumn);
  let maxChars = Math.ceil(columnWidth / range.getFontSize()) - 1;

  if (maxChars <= range.getValue().length) {
    range.setNote(range.getValue());
    range.setValue(range.getValue().substring(0,maxChars) + '...');
  }
}
```

Then to restore the current value use `=setCurrentValue()` in the cell:

```
function setCurrentValue() {
  let cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getCurrentCell();
  cell.setValue(cell.getNote());
  cell.setNote(undefined);
}
```

Edits done programatically are not handled by the `onEdit(e)` event.

### Reference

[Google Apps Script > Sheets: Custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

[Google Apps Script > Sheets: Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

[Google Apps Script > Sheets: Sheet.getColumnWidth](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getcolumnwidthcolumnposition)

Comment: Hi, just tested your proposal and the calculation is a good approximation to fit in the cell. I just played with -1 or -2 in order to see or not the grid lines. Many thanks for this well detailed solution!